# How can I reuse the uploaded images in Magento for another product?

Tags: magento

Using [Magento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento), is there a way to reuse the uploaded image for a product so that I can assign the same image to a different product?

Answer (score 1):

You could assign the same image to the file using the export import.  But this only works well if you are using one image.  What you could do is export your products, set the image to be the same file on them all and reimport.  That would set the image to be the same file.

Comment: I haven't tried this recently but Magento used to duplicate the file if you tried it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Since the values are ultimately just stored as string paths in the database, the solution to this would center around changing that database value rather than using the Magento uploader (since we know that will duplicate the image).

Answer (score 0):

There's a magento extension extension that makes this very easy

http://magvana.com/reuse-images-extension/